# Not able to access Web API created in same solution in an ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API & ASP.NET Core MVC project in the same solution.

I am able to access the Web API through Swagger. When I want to access the API from my MVC application, I was not able to do so.

Due to that not able to generate API logs.

For reference I will share my project architecture here with `program.cs` for both projects and the MVC controller code that I have written.

This is the Web APIs `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Project.Authorization;
using Project.Helper;
using Project.HelperFiles;
using Project.Models;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    var services = builder.Services;
    var env = builder.Environment;

    string? conString = ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString(builder.Configuration, "DBConnection");

    ConnectionClass.connectionString = conString;

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

    var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "Log" };

    var columnOpts = new ColumnOptions();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .MinimumLevel.Error()
                     .WriteTo.Console()
                     .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: conString, sinkOptions: sinkOpts, columnOptions: columnOpts).CreateLogger();

    builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

    var ui_url = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Web_UI_URL").GetChildren()
                       .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CORSProject",
                    builder =>
                        {
                            foreach (string url in ui_url)
                            {
                                builder.WithOrigins(url.Trim())
                                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                                       .AllowAnyMethod();
                            }
                        });
    });
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddDbContext<CourierDbContext>(
                   item => 
item.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"),
                   o => o.CommandTimeout(10 * 60)), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<CourierDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
            options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        });

    // configure DI for application services
    services.Scan(scan =>
        scan.FromCallingAssembly()
            .AddClasses()
            .AsMatchingInterface()
        );

    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("CORSProject");

//app.UseMiddleware<SerilogMiddleware>();

app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandleMiddleware>();

app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is the `program.cs` for the MVC application:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Following is the code for my `AuthController`:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Presentation.ReqResModel;


namespace Presentation.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7276/Auth/Login");
        string refreshToken = "";
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClient;
        public AuthController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {

            _httpClient = httpClientFactory;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login login)
        {

            using (var httpClient = _httpClient.CreateClient())
            {
                // Set any required headers for the API (if needed)
                // httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer YourAccessToken");
                var request = new
                {
                    UserName = login.Username,
                    Password = login.Password
                };

                // Prepare your form data payload
                var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Request", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request) },
                { "KeyData", "" },
                // Add more key-value pairs as needed for your form data
            };

                // Use FormUrlEncodedContent to convert the form data into a URL-encoded format
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
                try
                {
                    // Make the POST request to the external API
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl, content);

                    // Handle the response based on your needs
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Handle success
                        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponce>(responseData);
                        var resData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRespnseData>(res.Body);
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserDetails", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resData));
                        return View("Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle error
                        var errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return RedirectToAction("Login");
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    // Handle exceptions if any
                    return StatusCode(500, $"Error calling external API: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Signup()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ForgetPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult ResetPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the Swagger UI of the response I get from the Web API:

[image]

This is the error I get in the MVC project:

[image]

I have tried some other ways also but still getting the same error.
Apricate any help from the community.

Comment: post your logs instead of exception image

Comment: API are not hitting from the controller so not able to generate any log. I have updated my question.

Comment: Why are there two methods for Login and UserLogin?

Comment: Issue has been resolved 
The update code of AuthController has been updated into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls allow me to share my test result here to make it looks more clearly.

[image]

The error message you post in the screenshot indicating code error in the app, I trust you need to further investigate your application by adding break point to debug and find which line throws the 500 error.

By the way, since the calling is started in the controller, we don't need to set CORS policy in API application. CORS issue should happen when the calling is starting in a client but not in a server.

Comment: With your code reference, I was able to find the issue. The issue was found in the JWT middleware where it was adding extra content type to the request parameters so that's why it is giving me the error for the same,
I will update my Mvc Controller code in the Question so that I can close the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you API is not getting hit because of the extra slash coming after the URL. Clear it and try.

[image]

Edit :

I see there are two methods, "Login" and "UserLogin",
One is marked as HTTP Post, the other one is just a method which is accepting `formdata` and is actually calling the backend `webapi`.

So decide which method would call the backend api and then proceed with the code.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<LoginResponce> UserLogin(MultipartFormDataContent formData)
    {
        //Empty Object Not needed
        LoginResponce res = new LoginResponce();
        
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_httpClient.BaseAddress +  "/Login", formData);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponce>(data);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ajay Managaon will check and try

Comment: I did try with removing the extra slash from the URL it is still getting the same error.

Comment: Why there are two methods for Login? One is Login and Other "UserLogin"?

Comment: i have written it for ease of understanding for myself i will be removing that code once my issue is resolved